# string a split and paste prefix to the new split string

Tags: r

I need to split a bunch of strings by a common character but I need to retain the prefix of this split and paste it to the new split string. Here is an example of the first two strings in my vector data (there are many).

Example:

```
dat <- c("Dry Lake I & II", "Blue Moon 1 & 2", "Hardscrabble 2012 & 2013)
"Dry Lake I & II"
"Blue Moon 1 & 2"
```

needs to become:

```
"Dry Lake I" 
"Dry Lake II"
"Blue Moon 1"
"Blue Moon 2"
```

I can split with `strsplit` but I don't know how to complete the second part.

```
strsplit(dat, "&")
```

gives me:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Dry Lake I " " II" 
[[2]]
[1] "Blue Moon 1 " " 2"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to replace the `" & "`) with "Dry Lake" and `scan` to split the string into two

```
scan(text = sub(" & ", ",Dry Lake", str1, fixed = TRUE), sep=",",
          what = "", quiet = TRUE)
#[1] "Dry Lake I" "Dry LakeII"
```

#### Update

Using the updated data

```
scan(text = sub("^([A-Za-z ]+) ([I1]) \\&", "\\1 \\2,\\1", dat), 
              sep=",", what = "", quiet = TRUE)
#[1] "Dry Lake I"  "Dry Lake II" "Blue Moon 1" "Blue Moon 2"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Dry Lake I & II"
```

Comment: Thanks! Any way to make this dynamic? So for example Dry Lake is just one of the many strings that need to be split by "&"

Comment: @user1658170  Can you show a slightly better general example to understsand the issue

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version which might fit your needs:

```
x <- "Dry Lake I & II"
x <- sub("(.*) I & II", "\\1 I & \\1 II", x)
strsplit(x, "\\s+&\\s+")[[1]]

[1] "Dry Lake I"  "Dry Lake II"
```

The logic here is that we convert `<some content> I & II` into:

```
<some content> I & <some content> II
```

Then, we split on delimiter `&` to generate a character vector.  One flaw here is that the approach might not work if `&` could appear as part of the name.

Answer (score 1):

Match the three parts of the input placing them in a new string with the first part repeated and a newline between them.  Then  read that in effectively splitting at the newline.

```
readLines(textConnection(sub("(.*) (\\S+) & (\\S+)", "\\1 \\2\n\\1 \\3", dat)))
## [1] "Dry Lake I"  "Dry Lake II" "Blue Moon 1" "Blue Moon 2"
```